# can't run python script with crontab and startup application

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, cron

I have a simple python script that compares date of a file to the current date and prints something on screen.
I want to execute this script every time I log in.
I try to add the script to the startup application in Ubuntu that didn't work.
I tried to create a .sh file that have 'python3 code.py' in it and pass this sh file to crontab( through `crontab -e` command with `@reboot /passtofile/script.sh`) but I didn't get desired output.
what should I do?

Comment: First rule of cron: always use full paths, even for system-wide executables like `python` (so use `/usr/bin/python`). Second rule: use redirection to a log file for debugging. So do something like `/usr/bin/python /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/logfile 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, `crontab`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.